# Regular expression for UTF-8 words

Tags: php, regex

I am creating a shopping cart and I have a litle issue with regex.

What I would like to do, is to validate the product titles by allowing the end user to use the following characters:

words spaces : . -

my current regex is this

```
/^[\w \-\.\:]+$/i
```

but, when I try for example to paste some UTF-8 Characters like Greek alphabet characters or Chinese characters, Russian and so on, this regex fails.

**NOTE** : I already have try for the Greek characters to use the α-ωΑ-Ω as well the \x{0374}-\x{03FF} with no luck. Also this teqnique does not support other languages alphabets

So, is there a way to match all of these characters in one regex?

Comment: How do you define "words"? The definition of `\w` is pretty clear and does not include non-ASCII characters.

Comment: This is it. I am using the \w to match the single words. I know that not works with non-ASCII characters, but I don't know what to use.

Comment: If you allow virtually any character from virtually all languages, what *don't* you allow then and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\p{L}\p{M}` for the Posix groups Letters and combining diacritical Marks. Zero-width marks, accents, should not be forgotten because `é` can be written as one letter, but also as `letter-e` + `combining accent-acute`. And some alphabets have more than one accent to a letter.

As commented by @MeriaonosNikos do not forget the Unicode switch at the end of the regex `/u`.

Comment: That regex must replace my previews regex or I have to add these two entities extra ? Because I already test your entities by appending them at the end of my regex and doesn't work. This is what I currently have in my regex : /^[\w \-\.\:\p{L}\p{M}]+$/i

Comment: @Merianos You also have to add the `/u` modifier at the end of the regex for it to process UTF-8 at all.

Comment: @deceze this is what I was ready to post :) Thanks, I found out by my self that I have to use the /u modifier too. Anyway thanks a lot :)